# How to pass retrofit data in bundle to view pager fragments from activity?

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, retrofit2, bundle

In my activity i am receiving a game id from previous activity and using this id i am getting list of data from api. The method ("ApiCheats") in activity is used to get lis t of data.

I want to pass this list to my fragment in view pager, for this i used bundle but in fragment the bundle is null.

How should i pass bundle list to fragment , this data i am receiving through retrofit.

This is the Activity

```
 public class GameListCheatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = GameListCheatsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public List<Cheats> Cheats;
    ArrayList cheats = new ArrayList<Cheats>();
 //   public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    String Gameid;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    TabLayout tabLayout ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_list_cheats);
//        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_id);
//        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
//        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        Gameid = getIntent().getStringExtra("GameID");
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_id);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager());
        ApiCheats();
        adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment_Cheats(),"GameCheats");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment_Favourites(),"Favourites");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);




        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if(state == 0){
                    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cheatitem, null);




                }
                if(state == 1){
                    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cheatitem, null);

                }

            }
        });




    }

    public void ApiCheats()
    {
        ApiUtil.getServiceClass().getAllCheats(Gameid).enqueue(new Callback<List<Cheats>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Cheats>> call, Response<List<Cheats>> response) {
                if(response != null)
                {
                    if(response.isSuccessful())
                    {
                      Cheats =  response.body();

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("cheatslist", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) Cheats);
                        Fragment_Cheats fragment_cheats = new Fragment_Cheats();
                        fragment_cheats.setArguments(bundle);



                    }

                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Returned count " + Cheats.size());

                GameListCheatsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      //  CheatsAdapter adapter = new CheatsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Cheats);
                      //  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Cheats>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error loading from API");
            }
        });

    }



}
```

this is one of the fragments class

```
public class Fragment_Cheats extends Fragment   {


    View v;
    private RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    private List<Cheats> lstGameCheats;


    public Fragment_Cheats()
    {

    }


//    @Override
//    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//
//        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
//        if (bundle != null) {
//            lstGameCheats = bundle.getParcelable("cheatslist");
//        }
//
//    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment__cheats, container, false);
        mrecyclerview = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_cheats);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            lstGameCheats = bundle.getParcelable("cheatslist");
        }
        CheatsAdapter recyclerAdapter = new CheatsAdapter(getContext(),lstGameCheats);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        return  v;

    }

}
```

this is view pager adapter

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> lstFragment = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> lstTitles = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return lstFragment.get(position);
        //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lstTitles.size();
        //return 0;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return lstTitles.get(position);
    }


    public  void AddFragment(Fragment fragment,String title){

        lstFragment.add(fragment);
        lstTitles.add(title);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should set the `Cheats` to the Fragment which have added to your `ViewPagerAdater`, but according to your code you just set the data to a new fragment instance.
2. According to the `Fragment_Cheats` code, if you want to invoke getArgument() in onCreate() method, you should invoke fragment.setArgument() before the fragment add to the ViewPagerAdapter.

But in your situation it is not possible, because the data get from the network.

So, two step

1. Set data to the correct `Fragment_Cheats` instance
2. Notify `Fragment_Cheats` data changed, refresh the View state in the fragment

**Replace your onResponse()**

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Cheats>> call, Response<List<Cheats>> response) {
    if(response != null)
    {
        if(response.isSuccessful())
        {
            Cheats =  response.body();

            Fragment_Cheats fragment_cheats = adapter.getCheatFragment()
            fragment_cheats.setDatas(Cheats);
        }

    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Returned count " + Cheats.size());

    GameListCheatsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //  CheatsAdapter adapter = new CheatsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Cheats);
          //  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    });

}
```

**`Fragment_Cheats` add `setDatas()` method**

```
 public void setDatas(List<Cheats> datas) {
       this.lstGameCheats = datas;
       // and set the datas to the RecylerView adapter
       recyclerviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: sorry not understanding how to pass the data to fragment , i tried sending bundle but not getting any data there.

Comment: how to set Cheats to fragment

Comment: You can use mannnnnny ways to set `Cheats` to fragment.  Your code not work because you set data to a wrong fragment and  invoke `getArgument()` at a wrong timing. I have update my answer.